# Error Max LOB size (16777216) exceeded, actual size of parsed column is xxx, loading data to Snowflake via Matillion

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, matillion

I am trying to load data to a snowflake table using Matillion Database Query component. It gives the error "Error Max LOB size (16777216) exceeded, actual size of parsed column is xxx" while loading a JSON string to a Variant column in snowflake.
Is there a way to increase the max size while loading the data via Matillion?
Or is there any way to increase this max length value in the Database/Table level?

Comment: This is currently a limitation from Snowflake side, have a look [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-considerations)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to increase the size, as it's a hard limit on Snowflake (for now).

Please check the following KB for detailed explanation and some workarounds:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Max-LOB-size-exceeded

In summary, you may try to split out the arrays in your JSON.